# Loop and iteration question that iterates the wrong

Tags: python

I am trying to find the largest input number (see [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCRcf.png)), but I get an error instead.

```py
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")

    if (num == "done"):
        break
    try:        
        int(num)       
        
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue 

    if largest == None or int(num) > largest:
        largest = num
    elif smallest == None or int(num) < smallest:
        smallest = num
    
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

For example, when entering 33 then 8, I see

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/td/tmp/g/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    if largest == None or int(num) > largest:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: `largest = num`. You meant `largest = int(num)` (same for `smallest`)? In your current code after first valid input, `largest` and `smallest` will be of type `str`

Comment: Please post the problem as text, not an image. Less text than the original question is good. And include a note about what went wrong. Something along the lines of "I am trying to find the largest input value but (something) happens".

Comment: At the top of the `try`, remember the converted integer and use that for the rest of the program. `my_num  = int(num)` and then no need for more `int(num)` below.

Comment: Also include what is actually happening / going wrong. Down + close vote otherwise.

Comment: change your `elif` statement to an `if` statement. And you need to change the lines mentioned by @kuro.

Answer (score 0):

`num` is the original input string. When you save it to `largest` or `smallest`, its still a string, not an integer. In the next round, you then try to compare one to `int(num)`. But `str` and `int` can't be compared, hence the error. To fix, just remember that first conversion of str to int and use that value later on.

As a side note, `None` is one of the very few times that comparing with `is` is better than comparing with `None`. `None` is guaranteed to be a singleton so `is` always works. Although its safe with `int`, not all custom classes that override `__eq__` remember to test for `None`.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")

    if (num == "done"):
        break
    try:        
        num = int(num)       
        
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue 

    if largest is None or num > largest:
        largest = num
    elif smallest is None or num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```